# arguments of a function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am writing a function with two arguments and I want the second argument to be processed as a string. The following code encounters an error

function Derivative = derive ( Matrix9x1 , string Variable )
end

How can I tell it to matlab?
I mean even if the user inputs 1 as the second argument it should be processed as an string
and the user should be able to enter for example **omega**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to your function will only be processed 'as a string' if it '**is** a string', that is if you enclose it in single quotation marks. If you want to pass a number to a function and turn it into a string for further operations, use the function `num2str`. If you want to write a function which takes different actions depending on the type of the second argument you're going to have to test that type when the function is called; you might want to look at the functions `ischar`, `isstrprop`, `isnumeric`, and their relations.

Oh, and don't forget that a Matlab 'string' is really an array of characters which are just a convenience 'type' for integers-representing-characters.

Comment: Do you mean `num2str` instead of `str2num`?

Answer (score -1):

Matlab functions are unlike programming language functions. Not that your example in these programming languages will not work either. Passing an integer to a function that expects a string, will give you compilation errors.

The best alternative in Matlab that I can think of will be to check or convert the second input variable inside the function. Maybe this can help you: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/typecast.html

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is odd.  Matlab functions are (just like) programming language functions.  Many languages will complain if you pass an integer to a function expecting a string, either at run-time or compile-time.  And the ones that don't complain are hiding the truth from you, the truth that they do the necessary type cast on your behalf.

Comment: My point there is: In programming you explicit let the function demand a certain type of variable. In MATLAB it is not like that afaik.